# Prepared statement doesnt work with set role

Tags: java, jdbc

i am working with oracle roles and java and trying to set role via prepared statement but its giving me exception missing or invalid role name here is my function

```
 public static void setRole(String rn,String rp,Connection cn){
          try{
            PreparedStatement pstmt = cn.prepareStatement("SET ROLE ? IDENTIFIED BY ?");  
            pstmt.setString(1, rn);
            pstmt.setString(2, rp);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
           pstmt.close();
          }catch(Exception oops){
            oops.printStackTrace();;
          }
      }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: try to print your PS.

Comment: Try to run your query using sql commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pstmnt.execute()` rather than `executeUpdate()`

Some notes appear [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/ref/rrefsetrole.html)

Presumeably the change in role is associated with the connection object that you have executed the statement against.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check if the role you're trying to use exists. You can do that by running the sql query directly into the database cli.

Comment: i did when i execute it with SET ROLE test IDENTIFIED BY test it works but when i use ? it doesnt

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefsetrole.html Check this out. Might be useful!